# Angular question (Cannot read property 'genre' of undefined)

Tags: angular, undefined

I'm trying to build a simple app similar to a tour of heroes (official angular tutorial). I faced one problem I can't resolve as I think due to my bad understanding of fundamental programming knowledge.

Here's what I have:

```
ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.getMovie();
    this.getSimilarMovies();
}

getMovie(): any
{
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.httpService.viewDetails(id).subscribe(movie => this.movie = movie);
}
```

This function basically loads component of movie details (it takes an id of the movie and loads detail component)
and I was trying to write a function that was going to load an array of the same movie genre, so I need to extract the movie genre from the movie I chose

```
getSimilarMovies(): void
{
    const genre = this.movie.genre_ids[0];
    this.httpService.getMoviesByGenre(genre).subscribe(movies => this.similarMovies = movies.results);
}
```

it comes back as undefined. How can I fix it?
TIA

Comment: I didn't understand what's resulting undefined

Answer (score 1):

`this.movie` is not defined yet when you call `getSimilarMovies`. Let `getMovies` return an observable and get similar movies after it's done.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMovie().subscribe(movie => {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.getSimilarMovies();
      }, err => { // handle error }
    );
}

getMovie(): Observable<any> {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    return this.httpService.viewDetails(id);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Note that `subscribe` inside `subscribe` is an anti pattern in RxJs though. Prefer using a combinator like `mergeMap` to combine results of 2 observables.

Comment: Yeah @gaël-j I was also about to say that you should do that. Also calling `subscribe` in component code at all is an anti-pattern to me. Check `AsyncPipe`: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: To keep it simple, I'm not going to edit the answer though. That's a lesson for another time :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hi gogi15, to be able to help you I must see the code of the method "getMoviesByGenre()" your problem comes from there**

Can you show us the code of the method "getMoviesByGenre()" ?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment than an answer - it provides no solutions or details.

Comment: Yes, but I think we can’t comment on the original question!